# How to mock class async / await functions using mocha sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

How can i write test cases to class. i have a class with two methods inside it. i am accessing this class in my route by creating new object. now with test cases i have to mock the actual class method call. i am using sinon and mocha. it is still calling the original class.

how to write test case to my router

myclass1.js

```
export default class Detector {
    constructor() {}
    setDetectorStrategy(Detector) {
        this.detector = Detector;
    }
    getcontent = async(payload) => {
        console.log('kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
        const res = await this.getDetails(payload);
         return res;
    }

}
```

In myRoute.js

```
import Detector from '../services/detector';
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
let detector = new Detector();
 detector.setDetectorStrategy(new my());

 await detector.getcontent (payload);
   res.json({});
 });
```

Comment: Do you want to be sure your methods were called by your route, right? If so, I would recommend to Spy your classes. You could use Sinon to spy and get the information if your underline method was called once, twice, or not called at all.  I hope that helps !

Comment: var Detector = sinon.spy(function () {
        return sinon.createStubInstance(Detector);
      });

      var detector = new Detector();

      detector.getcontent.returns({});
 i try with this but i am getting cannot read property returns of undefined

Comment: can u share your comments on above finding

Comment: i found that issue is with async method. i have created a new sync method i am able to  create stub for it sinon.stub(detector.prototype, 'method').returns().. when i change back to async again issue arises.can u help

Comment: It is a long process to spy on a route that is on a web server. You need to use supertest. Since I cannot paste the GitHub link, I am posting it as an answer.

Comment: Remember that `async function`s are just `function`s that return promises. You know how to stub those, don't you?

Comment: @Bergi i presume that if the user knew it, the user wouldn't ask the question in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the example in GitHub below to see if it helps.

The spy, created with sinonjs, spies on the server variable (supertest) that encapsulates and runs the server.js and asserts with sinon's assert method to determine the number of times a request was made to the /about route define in the server.js file. You may need to modify the code to point to your route.

https://github.com/ravichandranjv/SpyingARoute/blob/master/test/usertest.js

Comment: Please post your solution code in the answer, instead of just a link to it.

Comment: Trying to stub property 'getContent' of undefined

Comment: Please either post the screenshot of the error by updating it in the question or provide some additional code or the test code.